# Problems incorporating Bootstrap 4 navbar with wordpress 4.x

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Working on a incorporating bootstrap navbar with wordpress and it is not working for me. Below is the wordpress wp_nav_menu function and my commented out code for the navbar (which works). Weird thing I notices is that the wordpress puts the classes at the wrong places.

```
<?php
   wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location'   => 'primary',
      'menu'             => 'primary',
      'container'        => 'div',
      'container_class'  => 'navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end',
      'menu_class'       => 'nav navbar-nav'
                    ) );
?>
<!-- <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="nav-item"><a href="/" class="nav-link">Test 1</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"><a href="/" class="nav-link">Test 2</a</li>           
        </ul>
     </div> 
-->
```

Wordpress builds html as follows which ofcourse breaks as classes are not applied  at the right nodes. ul has no classes where as the container has the wrong classes.

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav">
   <ul>
      <li class="page_item page-item-12"><a 
      href="http://localhost/fmr/Test1">Test 1</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-8 current_page_item"><a 
      href="http://localhost/fmr/">Test 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: I just tested it on WordPress 4.9.7 and it's working fine. I'm getting the expected result. I wonder is there a plugin messing with it. Did you go through the usual WordPress debugging - turning on and off plugins and themes etc?

Comment: This looks like similar behaviour to your problem https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_nav_menu-menu_class-usage-bug/?replies=4 and there's a solution posted here: http://thinkncode.com/menu-classes-not-coming-in-html-with-menu_classnav-solved-wp_nav_menu-wordpress/ . Have you tried it?

Comment: @DerekNolan No I have not the usual wordpress debugging because I don't know what that means :-) I have worked with wordpress over the years at a minimal level. This time I'm trying to get into it in a little depth. As for turning on/off the plugins. I don't have any plugins yet. So don't think that is the issue here

Comment: @DerekNolan I tried the solution above. It suggests adding 'fallback_cb'      => 'false' but now the menu has totally disappeared.

Comment: Does the menu exist? 'menu' => 'primary', suggests that you have set up a menu in the backend called 'primary'.

Comment: @DerekNolan Yes it does. I'm looking into implementing this: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Comment: @DerekNolan Something you said above made me solve the issue. Menu was there but name was not correct. I had primary as menu name whereas the name was: Main Menu! So thank you for making me look at it again.

Comment: I was just about to ask you to double check it!

Comment: Shall I post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the settings array, the menu is set to **primary**. This should be set to the title of the menu in the back end. In this case, menu should be **Main Menu**.

```
<?php
   wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location'   => 'primary',
      'menu'             => 'Main Menu',
      'container'        => 'div',
      'container_class'  => 'navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end',
      'menu_class'       => 'nav navbar-nav'
   ) );
?>
```